# Show a Facebook like box for the same page on different domains

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-page, facebook-likebox

I have two web sites, let's say one is dedicated to cooking southern chicken, and another to southern barbeque.  Instead of creating two separate Facebook pages, I want to create a single Facebook page and call it, for example Southern Cooking, and show a popup box to like that page on both sites.  Is this technically possible?

Comment: You can put the Facebook Like button plugin on as many external websites as you want.

Comment: I am talking about a like box, not a like button.  A like button can be linked to a URL or a page, whereas a like box can only be linked to a Facebook page, and the linking has to be done via an app, as far as I understand.

Comment: Ah, my bad. Anyhow, the [Like Box plugin is deprecated](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-box-for-pages), so you should use the new Page plugin anyway (which is what the Like box will automatically fall back to after June 23rd 2015). And I think you can use both without an app id actually, if you simply remove the app id from the initialization code it should still work. And even if it didn’t, then all you would need to do is create two apps, one for each external website that you want to initialize the JS SDK on …

Comment: The only way to have the app ID removed is to insert the admin's user ID number into the code, which in this case is my personal ID, since I am the manager, and I don't want to do that for privacy reasons.

Comment: No idea what you’re talking about. I just tested it – the page plugin works perfectly fine when the app id from the JS SDK initialization code is removed, without inserting any user ID anywhere.

Comment: I will test that, thanks.  But what did you mean earlier when you said "all you would need to do is create two apps, one for each external website"?  The whole point of this exercise is to collect likes from two sites and pool them into one fan page.  Is it possible to tie two apps to one page?

Comment: The likes are given by users to the fan page, by you pointing the page plugin to that fan page as the target – where and how that happens does not matter. You can easily use two different apps to _embed_ the plugin, that doesn’t change what the likes are counted for, and doesn’t need the apps to be “tied” to anything.

Comment: I believe you might be wrong there.  I clearly remember integrating a like box in the past that wasn't working, because the domain was different from the one specified in the app that was tied to the page.

Comment: But I think this discussion is moot.  I just checked the code for the new Page plugin, and all you need is a URL of the Facebook page.  You are no longer required to create an app and connect it to your page, like you did with the Like Box.  So thank you for indirectly solving my issue. :)